# Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: css, html

This is the basic idea: http://i51.tinypic.com/1zwcbgn.jpg

So I made it like this (notice it is fluid): http://twomuchwork.com/test

Is there a better way to do this than the way I did?

Comment: What's the issue here? Looks ok as far as I can tell

Comment: IE6 is displaying small irregularity where you can see the sidebar at the bottom of the footer at some browser window sizes, so maybe you can fix it with a bottom margin on the sidebar. Otherwise it looks fine and pretty concise.

Comment: I was just wondering if there could be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with how you did it, but since you're asking, here's my go-to reference for pretty much any multi-column HTML+CSS-JavaScript layout:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths

Comment: @Kragen: no problem. I came across it (via SO, of course) a few months ago and it is the best thing _evar_.